# Switch icons after user scrolls past div

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Goal

When the audio clip is paused and the user scrolls past a blockquote inside the story, I'm looking to switch the FontAwesome icon from `volume-off` back to its default of `volume-up`. Then, reset the audio clip back to the start.

## Problem

However, the switch happens pretty much immediately, instead of when the blockquote is out of view. **My if statement seems off**. Wondering if I have to include something like `innerHeight` of the element in addition to its offset to ensure this doesn't happen. Been console.log() a bunch of things to little success.

### scripts.js

```
// Position of the blockquotes
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

var bathtubOffset = $(".bathtub").offset();
var behindOffset = $(".behind").offset();
var curiousOffset = $(".curious").offset();
var haystackOffset = $(".haystack").offset();
var wishesOffset = $(".wishes").offset();

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if (scroll >= bathtubOffset && bathtub.paused == true) {
        $(".bathtub").removeClass("fa-volume-off");
        $(".bathtub").addClass("fa-volume-up");
        bathtub.currentTime = 0 // Reset audio clip to the beginning
    }
});
```

### index.html

```
            <blockquote class="blockquote--simple">
                <audio id="wishes">
                   <source src="assets/audio/mp3/wishes.mp3">
                   <source src="assets/audio/ogg/wishes.ogg">
                </audio>

                <p class="blockquote__text--simple">"Put your wishes down because that was the hardest thing that we dealt with was not knowing what he wanted." </p>

                <div class="blockquote__icons">
                    <p>— Brian Fowell</p>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/home?status=%22Put%20your%20wishes%20down%20because%20that%20was%20the%20hardest%20thing%20that%20we%20dealt%20with%22%20http%3A//bdnsun.ca/bdnhoarders%0A" target="_blank"><i class="blockquote__icon--simple fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <i class="blockquote__icon--simple fa fa-volume-up wishes inline"></i>
                </div>
            </blockquote>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are never refreshing `scroll` and you're not using the `top` property of `bathtubOffset`.

`var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();` is called in a global scope and never set inside your listener.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    //Update scroll
    scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    //Also change to using bathtubOffset.top
    if (scroll >= bathtubOffset.top && bathtub.paused == true) {
        $(".bathtub").removeClass("fa-volume-off");
        $(".bathtub").addClass("fa-volume-up");
        bathtub.currentTime = 0 // Reset audio clip to the beginning
    }
});
```

*EDIT: As @GreggDuncan points out, `bathtubOffset is the object with all the offset values. It needs`.top`*

jQuery's [`offset` method](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) returns an object holding all of the offset values for the DOM element. This includes `top`, `left`, `height`, etc. Your scrolling method is only looking at *vertical* scrolling, you only need the `top` value. So you access the `offset`'s property for that: `bathtubOffset.top`.

Comment: Also bathtubOffset is an object. You want to use bathtubOffset.top;

Comment: @GreggDuncan I missed that. Thanks, I added the edit.

Comment: @DonRhummy Worked like a charm. a) Just hoping you could elaborate on the difference between bathtubOffset and bathtubOffset.top?

Comment: @AndrewNguyen Added an explanation to the bottom of my answer.